# ¿Por que no guarda la url de la imagen en mi base de datos?

Tags: nodejs, express, sequelize.js, multer

Estoy utilizando **Node/express** y **multer** para la imagen, desde un formulario le envio los datos y la imagen al servidor,(la imagen se guarda perfectamente en mi carpeta **public/images**) y con **Sequelize** guardo los datos en **MySql**.
Cuando me fijo en la tabla de mi base de datos, efectivamente guarda todos los datos, pero la **url** **de la imagen** no.

Aca el formulario (estoy usando **Pug** como plantilla)

```html
h1 Subir Datos
div
    form(action="http://localhost:3000/api/posts", method="POST", enctype="multipart/form-data")
        label Title
        input(type="text", name="title")
        label Content
        input(type="text", name="content")
        label Category
        input(type="text", name="categoryId")
        label Creation Date
        input(type="text", name="creationDate")
        label Imagen
        input(type="file", name="image")
        input(type="submit", value="Enviar")
```

Aca la **ruta** que recibe los datos del formulario que ademas con **multer** valido el tamaño y extension .jpg .png etc..

```js
const router = require("express").Router();

// ******************* PARA HACER UPLOAD DE IMAGE ******************* //
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require('path');
const uuid = require("uuid");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callBack) => {
      //carpeta donde va a guardar las imgs
      callBack(null, "public/images");
    },
    filename: (req, file, callBack) => {
      // uuid.v4() guarda la img con id aleatorio, para que no
      // se pisen imagenes en el caso que se suban con el mismo nombre
      callBack(
        null,
        uuid.v4() + path.extname(file.originalname).toLocaleLowerCase()
      );
    },
  });
  
  const upload = multer({
    storage,
    dest: "images/",
  
    limits: { fileSize: 2000000 }, // max permitido de image, 2 mega byte de peso
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
      const fileTypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/; // expresion regular
      // mimetype checkea si el archivo es valido ej img/extension del archivo
      const mimetype = fileTypes.test(file.mimetype);
      // path.extname checkea si la img tiene la extension .jpeg o .jpg o .gif o .png
      const extname = fileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname));
      if (mimetype && extname) {
        return cb(null, true);
      } else {
        cb("Error: el archivo debe ser una imagen valida");
      }
    },
  }).single("image");
  
  router.route("/file").post(upload, (req, res, next) => {
    // const file = (req).file;
    const file = req.body.image;
    console.log(file);
    if (!file) {
      console.log("No se subió ninguna imagen");
    }
    res.send(file);
    var ruta = (req).file.path;
    console.log("ruta de imagen: " + ruta);
  });
  
  // ******************* FIN UPLOAD DE IMAGE ******************* //

// model sequelized from db.js file
const { Post } = require("../../db");

router.post("/", upload, async (req, res) => {
    const post = await Post.create(req.body);
    res.json(post);
});
```

Aca mi archivo **db.js**

```js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

// import model
const PostModel = require("./models/post");

const sequelize = new Sequelize("xxxx", "xxx", "xxx", {
  host: "remotemysql.com",
  dialect: "mysql",
  define: {
    timestamps: false
  }
});

const Post = PostModel(sequelize, Sequelize);

sequelize.sync({ force: false })
.then(() => {
    console.log('Tablas sincronizadas')
})

module.exports = {
  Post,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de esta forma:

```js
router.post("/", upload, async (req, res) => {
  const postObj = {
    title: req.body.title,
    content: req.body.content,
    image: req.file.path,
    categoryId: req.body.categoryId,
    creationDate: req.body.creationDate,
  };

  const post = await Post.create(postObj);
  res.json(post);
});
```